# parse new command throws Syntax error

Tags: python, linux, parse-platform

I am trying parse for the first time and I used curl to install the parse script but whenever I try the command I get a Syntax error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2222, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2164, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1940, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1916, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1897, in _legacy_get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 863, in spec_from_loader
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 904, in spec_from_file_location
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 481
    os.chmod(executor, 0755)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I think I could fix the error by passing an octal instead of a decimal there but I cant edit the code. My only option is to somehow get my python2 in my system to execute it instead of python 3.4

How can I do that ?

No I cannot remove python 3.4 there are a lot of dependencies on it.

Comment: `0755` is an invalid mode !

Comment: Yes I can set it as 0o755 to fix it but just like I mentioned I cannot edit the code..